# @Autowired service inside of @Component returns null pointer exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, autowired

My Spring Web App returns `java.lang.NullPointerException` when I try to use a service which is Autowired inside a component.

I tried solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19896870/why-is-my-spring-autowired-field-null) but it didn't work for me since I am already using `@component`.

Here is my full exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ir.yasharne.rpi.websocket.MyStompSessionHandler.handleFrame(MyStompSessionHandler.java:81)
    at org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.DefaultStompSession.invokeHandler(DefaultStompSession.java:448)
    at org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.DefaultStompSession.handleMessage(DefaultStompSession.java:399)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.messaging.WebSocketStompClient$WebSocketTcpConnectionHandlerAdapter.handleMessage(WebSocketStompClient.java:342)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.client.AbstractClientSockJsSession.handleMessageFrame(AbstractClientSockJsSession.java:271)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.client.AbstractClientSockJsSession.handleFrame(AbstractClientSockJsSession.java:213)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.client.WebSocketTransport$ClientSockJsWebSocketHandler.handleTextMessage(WebSocketTransport.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.handler.AbstractWebSocketHandler.handleMessage(AbstractWebSocketHandler.java:43)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.adapter.standard.StandardWebSocketHandlerAdapter.handleTextMessage(StandardWebSocketHandlerAdapter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.adapter.standard.StandardWebSocketHandlerAdapter.access$000(StandardWebSocketHandlerAdapter.java:42)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.adapter.standard.StandardWebSocketHandlerAdapter$3.onMessage(StandardWebSocketHandlerAdapter.java:81)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.adapter.standard.StandardWebSocketHandlerAdapter$3.onMessage(StandardWebSocketHandlerAdapter.java:78)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsFrameBase.sendMessageText(WsFrameBase.java:395)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsFrameBase.processDataText(WsFrameBase.java:495)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsFrameBase.processData(WsFrameBase.java:294)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsFrameBase.processInputBuffer(WsFrameBase.java:133)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsFrameClient.processSocketRead(WsFrameClient.java:95)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsFrameClient.resumeProcessing(WsFrameClient.java:209)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsFrameClient.access$300(WsFrameClient.java:31)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsFrameClient$WsFrameClientCompletionHandler.doResumeProcessing(WsFrameClient.java:186)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsFrameClient$WsFrameClientCompletionHandler.completed(WsFrameClient.java:163)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsFrameClient$WsFrameClientCompletionHandler.completed(WsFrameClient.java:148)
    at sun.nio.ch.Invoker.invokeUnchecked(Invoker.java:126)
    at sun.nio.ch.Invoker$2.run(Invoker.java:218)
    at sun.nio.ch.AsynchronousChannelGroupImpl$1.run(AsynchronousChannelGroupImpl.java:112)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

line 81 is `moduleService.saveModule(module);` in `MyStompSessionHandler.java`:

```
@Component
public class MyStompSessionHandler extends StompSessionHandlerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private ModuleService moduleService;

    @Override
    public void afterConnected(StompSession session, StompHeaders connectedHeaders) {
        session.subscribe("/topic/messages", this);
    }

    @Override
    public Type getPayloadType(StompHeaders headers) {
        return ServerMessage.class;
    }

    @Override
    public void handleFrame(StompHeaders headers, Object payload) {
        ServerMessage message = (ServerMessage) payload;
        if (message.getTopic().equals("newModule")){
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            try {
                Map<String, Object> readValue = mapper.readValue(message.getMessage(), Map.class);
                int id = (int) readValue.get("id");
                boolean programmable = (boolean) readValue.get("programmable");
                float value = Float.parseFloat(readValue.get("value").toString());
                Module module = new Module();
                module.setId(id);
                module.setProgrammable(programmable);
                module.setValue(value);
                moduleService.saveModule(module);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("HandlerFrame: ");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void handleException(StompSession session, StompCommand command, StompHeaders headers, byte[] payload, Throwable exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and my `WebAppConfiguration.java`:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "ir.yasharne.rpi")
public class WebAppConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return viewResolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registery){
        registery.addResourceHandler("/static/**").addResourceLocations("/static/");
    }
}
```

`ModuleServiceImpl.java`:

```
@Service("moduleService")
@Transactional
public class ModuleServiceImpl implements ModuleService {

    @Autowired
    private ModuleDao moduleDao;

    @Override
    public void saveModule(Module module) {
        moduleDao.saveModule(module);
    }
}
```

How can I fix it?

BTW, I can Autowire and use `moduleService` inside of controller and use it with no problem

Comment: What is the package of `ModuleServiceImpl` ?

Comment: @Berger `package ir.yasharne.rpi.service.impl;`

Comment: I had same problems. Solved them with passing parameters to constructor.

Comment: @Abdelhak I update my question, I can use it inside of controller so I think Component scan is not the problem

Comment: can you set up a minimalistic example on github and post that? There doesnt seem to be anything missing in your code. You also say that you dont get the NPE when you use the service in your controller, so I suspect there is something with the DI in `MyStompSessionHandler `... though not sure.. A github code I could work with ..this is not enough

Comment: An `@Autowired` field cannot be `null` in a Spring Managed bean. It can only be `null` if it isn't managed by Spring. So you must be doing `new MyStompSessionHandler()` in your code.

Comment: @M.Deinum actually I did `new MyStompSessionHandler()` on contextInitialization and works fine until I try to use `moduleService`

Comment: Don't create a new instance unless it is in a `@Bean` method (which makes it a Spring Bean).

Comment: @M.Deinum creating new instance inside of Bean annotated method solved the problem.

Comment: You don't need a new instance with a `@Bean` method. It already is a `@Component` and will be detected.

Answer (score 0):

What's the package for `MyStompSessionHandler`? I'm guessing it's not covered under `ir.yasharne.rpi`. Try moving it under that package (`ir.yasharne.rpi`), or update `@ComponentScan(basePackages = "ir.yasharne.rpi")` to `@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"ir.yasharne.rpi", "package.of.MyStompSessionHandler"})`

I'm guessing `MyStompSessionHandler` is not on the "component scan" path and that's why autowired dependencies within it are not picked.